# How do I append CSS values in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm using GWT table which is being generate dynamically with lots of columns but with out horizontal scroll bar and to get the scrollbar, we need wrapper with fixed width around the table, but GWT do create container but not adding any width to it.

To solve the problem, I'm calculating width of screen and adding it to the table wrapper, which is adding scroll bar to the table but working weirdly.

1. It adds scroll bar when I move mouse near to table
2. It doesn't work when in resize the table

I'm using `Live()` as  it works for run time objects, also I can't use click event.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    $('body').live("mouseover", function() {
        $('.scrollbar').css({
            'width' : (screenwidth) - 40
        });
        $("body").unbind("mouseover");
    });
});
```

Comment: your intentions aren't clear. please be more specific and elaborate on the components used (is it a flex-table? etc.), thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Use $('body').on("mouseover")
   If you are getting scrollbar you can handle that by setting up overflow to none.
   If you need to change css dynamically you can add / remove class and keep css separate from your code.  Its a good practice.

Comment: Sorry if you guys didn't get me. Well I've a table with lots of columns which is not fitting in the screen, so the solutions would be scroll bar & for this we need a wrapper with fixed width and overfow-x=scroll property. But the table i'm working is getting generated by GWT Component in run time. Which gets loaded after the execution of Jquery and to overcome this problem i'm using live() method. refer the above code pls.
 Now the problem is the scroll bar comes when i move mouse on the screen which is weird.

Comment: please make a demo on jsfiddle if possible this will be easy for anyone to check and help you. Thanks